# Execute a Linux Command to a Linux Server via Windows Powershell

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh, radius, google-authenticator

I would like to execute commands on my Radius Server (Amazon Linux) via Windows Powershell

These are the commands:

1. useradd -g radius-enabled **username**
2. yes -- -1 | sudo -u **username** google-authenticator -l testlabel -i testissuer -t -d -w 5 --no-rate-limit -f

**1** basically adds a user then **2** creates an mfa token for the created user
This needs to be done via Windows Powershell so I can try to make a powershell script later on

First, I tried to manually SSH to the Linux Server via Powershell module SSHSessions:
(i have installed the SSHSession module, configured my sshd_config)

> New-SshSession -ComputerName ? -Username  -Password

> Enter-SshSession -ComputerName

> [ServerIPAddress]: /home/username # :

It shows that I have SSHed to the server and I am able to execute some commands such as "df -h"
but when I try to sudo, change directory or execute other commands, It just hangs and I cant stop it.

What would be the proper/best way to execute this? I have tried searching for related topics but it wouldn't fit my situation. I decided to ask a question here to be more specific and maybe gain reputation so I can upvote that other stackoverflow answers that helped me.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to think about creating an API on the linux server, that you can call from the powershell script.

Comment: You're not gonna like this, but the proper way would be to use putty. If your job requires sshing into other servers, a tool like putty is the best option. It can even save username and ip's that way you can just type password and you're in with a double click of the servername. And if you have a large list of servers, superputty is a sweet wrapper to have a tree structure listing of all servers.